# How to add menu?

Tags: android, activitygroup

I use group for tabhost.
In MyGroup, below code to call AActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);  
Window w = NASGroup.group.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("AActivity", intent);  
View view = w.getDecorView();
MyGroup.group.setContentView(view);
```

Show AActivity and menu button works.
Then, I try use AActivity to call BActivity as below code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AActivity.this, BActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);  
Window w = NASGroup.group.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("BActivity", intent);  
View view = w.getDecorView();
MyGroup.group.setContentView(view);
```

BActivity show, but the menu button does not work without any error message.
I also try call BActivity by MyGroup as below code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, BActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);  
Window w = NASGroup.group.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("BAActivity", intent);  
View view = w.getDecorView();
MyGroup.group.setContentView(view);
```

BActivity show, and menu button works.
If I still want to call BActivity by AActivity.
How can I do?

Comment: are you using `ActivityGroup` to show tabhost?

Comment: Yes, I use ActivityGroup to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding separate menus in your child activity classes, add all the menus together in your parent class which extends **ActivityGroup**. and implement `OnTabChangeListener` to detect the chosen activity tab and alter (show/hide) your menus accordingly

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly:

In activity A:

```
Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), B.class);
startActivity(nextScreen);
```

and add this to your manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".B"></activity>
```

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html:

> all activity classes must have a corresponding  declaration
>   in their package's AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I has add in AndroidManifest. Because of TabHost, I want to use group to show each activity.

Comment: i guess his activities are working fine (no issues in manifest). The problem is with menu loading

Comment: I also define onCreateOptionsMenu and onPrepareOptionsMenu.